# Prime factorisation for large amount of numbers

Tags: c++, prime-factoring

So I have to make prime factorisation for up to 10^6 different numbers from 1 to 8*10^6. I've done this with Sieve of Erathostenes, but it seems that it's too slow. I have no idea how can I deal with it. Here's my code:

```
int factors[8000001] = { };

void sieve(int* tab, int max)
{
    for (int i = 2; i * i < max; ++i)
    {
        if(tab[i] == 0)
        {
            for (int j = i; j * i < max; ++j)
            {
                if (tab[i*j] > i || tab[i*j] == 0) 
                    tab[i*j] = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in main():

```
cin >> number;

while (number > 1)
{
if (factors[number] == 0)
    {
      cout << number;
      number = 1;
    }
    else if (number != factors[number])
        cout << factors[number] << "*";
    else
        cout << factors[number];
    number /= factors[number];
}
cout << "\n";
```

For smaller tests it works perfectly, but not for large ones. What can I improve? (I'm also using ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); line)

Comment: Is tab the same as factors[]? Also, don't you have integer overflow?

Comment: Yep, tab is equal to factors (it is a pointer to factors, to be more specific), I pass it to sieve() function. I'm almost sure there's no intiger overflow, all the numbers are smaller than 8*10^6, intiger is up to 2,147,483,647. 
EDIT: factors[] is in global range

Comment: Do you have to print the factors in increasing order? If not, the if conditions in sieve() can be removed.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it has to be an increasing order, the star after every factor is also crucial :/